# How to rotate a point using transformations.py

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, rotation

How do you use the popular  [transformations.py library](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/transformations.py.html) to rotate a point around an axis?

I'm trying to rotate a point 90 degrees about the z-axis, but I'm not getting the expected results, and although the file's docs have several examples of creating transformation matrices, it doesn't actually show how to use these matrices to apply the transformation. My code is:

```
from math import pi
import transformations as tf
import numpy as np

alpha, beta, gamma = 0, 0, pi/2.
origin, xaxis, yaxis, zaxis = (0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)
Rx = tf.rotation_matrix(alpha, xaxis)
Ry = tf.rotation_matrix(beta, yaxis)
Rz = tf.rotation_matrix(gamma, zaxis)
R = tf.concatenate_matrices(Rx, Ry, Rz)

point0 = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0]])

point1 = R * point0
#point1 = R * point0.T # same result
#point1 = np.multiply(R, point0) # same result
#point1 = np.multiply(R, point0.T) # same result
point1_expected = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0]])

assert point1.tolist() == point1_expected.tolist() # this fails
```

This calculates point1 as:

```
[[  0.00000000e+00  -1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   6.12323400e-17   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]]
```

which makes no sense to me. Multiplying a 4x4 matrix by a 4x1 matrix should result in a 4x1, not another 4x4. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`transformations.py` works with `np.array` objects, not `np.matrix`, even in the `whatever_matrix` functions. (This is a good thing, because `np.matrix` is horrible.) You need to use `dot` for matrix multiplication:

```
point1 = R.dot(point0)
```

Also, you've made `point0` a row vector for some reason. It should either be a column vector or a plain 1-dimensional vector:

```
point0 = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0])
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true, and just gives me a different error, `ValueError: shapes (4,4) and (1,4) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)`. If I do `R.dot(point0.T)`, then I get the nonsensical vector `[[-1, 6.12, 0, 0]]`.

Comment: @Cerin: For some reason, you've made a 1x4 array instead of 4x1. (You should probably be using a 1-dimensional array for the vector instead of 2-dimensional, though.) As for the 6.12, you're not looking at the exponent. It's 6.12e-17, which is 0 up to rounding error.

Comment: You're right, I missed the exponent, and my rotation sign was backwards. Thanks.